# is there a way to solve shader compiler error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, cross-platform, mobile-development

I was trying to run my flutter app and I got this error how do I resolve it?

```
#0      ShaderCompiler.compileShader (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/shader_compiler.dart:200:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      writeBundle.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/bundle_builder.dart:191:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:525:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      writeBundle (package:flutter_tools/src/bundle_builder.dart:169:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      WebDevFS.update (package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/devfs_web.dart:871:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      ResidentWebRunner._updateDevFS (package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/resident_web_runner.dart:520:35)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      ResidentWebRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/resident_web_runner.dart:308:41)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
```